# Tool tip to show plot values in Qwt

Tags: c++, qwt

I have a qwt plot in my application. I want to show a small tool tip to show the value of the point at which mouse is pointed on the curve. I found that I have to use QwtPlotPicker for this, but couldn't find any proper example to implement this in my code. I am new to Qwt so it would be great if anyone could help me solve this problem.

Thanks, Rakesh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The author himself says [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/17897-Get-the-plot-curve-to-which-the-mouse-is-pointing-to):

> A QwtPlotPicker gives you the current position of the mouse ( in screen and plot coordinates ). Then you need to find the closest points of your curves. You can use QwtPlotCurve::closestPoint(), but in most cases you can find a much faster implementation depending on the characteristics of your data.
>   When you need to compare the mouse position with the lines between the points you need the pixel position of these points ( use QwtPlot::canvasMap ). 
>   Maybe looking at the CanvasPicker of the eventfilter example helps.

I implemented it in my own class, which is a subclass of QwtPlot. In the constructor I have the following:

```
QwtPlotPicker* plotPicker = new QwtPlotPicker(this->xBottom, this->yLeft, QwtPicker::CrossRubberBand, QwtPicker::AlwaysOn, this->canvas());
QwtPickerMachine* pickerMachine = new QwtPickerClickPointMachine();
plotPicker->setStateMachine(pickerMachine);
connect(plotPicker, SIGNAL(selected(const QPointF&)), this, SLOT(onSelected(const QPointF&)));
```

Now in my class (where the this pointer refers to) I should implement the slot `onSelected(const QPointF&)` which will give the plot coordinates.

Comment: Can you tell me if there is a way to always send the signal mouse moved at poistion of the canvas with QwtPlotPicker, please?