# How to get the specific coordinates where mouse clicking on qwtplot?

Tags: c++, qt, qwt

I am working on a project with qwt. And what I am trying to do is obtaining the coordinates where my mouse click on. I searched on the Internet and find it might be relevant to the QwtPlotPicker class. But I can't find any function that may meet my need in the official document. Is there any example I can refer to? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066035/tool-tip-to-show-plot-values-in-qwt

Comment: actually it is parts of an unfinished project, is the source code really needed? It is kind of messy.

Comment: Check the link that you put in my next comment, there is your answer.

Comment: Here is another example: https://github.com/pvbrowser/pvb/blob/master/qwt/examples/bode/bode.cpp

Comment: thanks, I am studying on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tool tip to show plot values in Qwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066035/tool-tip-to-show-plot-values-in-qwt)

Comment: I try the code in "Tool tip to show plot values in Qwt", but what I get is coordinates floating around my mouse, but I still can't understand how to get the exact values stored in variables. http://imgur.com/a/pLAiN

Comment: Do you want the position in pixels or do you want the point on the plot?

Comment: yes, I want the point on the plot.

Comment: You can share your project even if it is not finished, so you can start testing it.

Comment: Here is my project. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7VyGeuv2EoGZW11SENwdUdLQU0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That code works, if you realize it shows you the position of the click with respect to the plot.

Comment: Please you could explain something more detailed because it seems that your explanation is ambiguous.

Comment: Actually, I don't even need anything to be displayed on my screen. I want to get the position coordinates in silence after I clicking my mouse(nothing should be displayed), and pass the value to other function that do the further operation.

Comment: Para obtener la posición lo debes a traves de la señal selected de QwtPlotPicker, para poder verlo en la clase LSPlot este debe heredar de QObject, todas esas modificaciones la hice en el siguiente link:  https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/RE_LightScan